# Ruby: Name a method for later definition?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a small ruby script that will have two methods (`TrySlot` and `LookAtCut`).  Each method needs to be able to call the other method.  When ruby is parsing the first method, it fails because it doesn't understand the name of the second method, since I haven't defined it yet.

So, how do I tell ruby, there is a method called `TrySlot` that I will define later so I can call `TrySlot` in my definition for `LookAtCut`?

Comment: It is always super helpful if you show some Ruby code that would reproduce the problem you're seeing. Defining two methods with both referencing the other does not produce and error. That would only happen if you were to call one of the methods before the other method that it referenced was defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting problems is that Ruby usually assumes all names starting with an uppercase letter to be constants. However, it will also let you define methods with a name starting by an uppercase letter. What is happening is the following:

- Ruby sees `def LookAtCut` and correctly defines a method named `LookAtCut`
- Inside `LookAtCut`, Ruby sees `TrySlot`, assumes it is a constant, tries to find it and fails with an error, since it hasn't been defined.

The solution would be not to use method names starting with uppercase characters. Then, you can use a method that hasn't been defined yet inside another one:

```
def a
  b
end

def b
  puts "Hello!"
end

a #=> "Hello!"
```

Comment: Ah.  Is there an overview somewhere of Ruby's thoughts on capitalization that I could read over?  There are probably other gotchas like this lurching for me...  (that did fix it BTW - thx)

Comment: It's fairly simple. Everything that is capitalized is a constant. As an informal standard, class constants are camel cased - `MyClass`. Non-class constants are caps with underscores - `DATE_FORMATS`. Methods and variables are lowercased and underscored `my_method`, `my_variable`.